# Apply a jQuery function to a specific variable

Tags: jquery

I would like to get the flip_error() applied only to these input fields which have an empty value. As it stands it gets applied to all of them:

```
function flip_error(element){
    element.addClass('flipped');
}

function add_color(element, color){
    element.css('background-color', color);
}

    $('form input:not(.submit, .email, .test)').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            flip_error(input.parent()); 
        }

        else {
            add_color($(this), white);
        }

    });
```

See full code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mM6Uh/3/)

The issue is that when I click on submit for the first time and without entering any text in the input fields the flip to red (another input field) and it's fine so far. However If I fill one of the input fields in with text it still flips to red and that's wrong as it needs to get the add_color() function applied.

Comment: Please provide add_color function

Comment: you need to reset the class in the other condition

Comment: As a complete side note: the whitespace between the close-brace of your `if` and the `else` (or any following code that should be attached) is a GREAT way to introduce bugs in the future.  Don't put whitespace between things that are related.  From page 78 of "Clean Code" by Robert C. Martin: "Each blank line is a visual cue that identiﬁes
a new and separate concept."  `if-else` isn't a new, separate concept, and shouldn't be separated like that.

Comment: thanks for the side note rockerest, any tips or help with the question above please?